# Submitting a form from Vue component to POST data into django backend database

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js

Where is the relationship between a form (found in a vue component) and a django backend meant to be defined?

For my frontend, I am using VueJS, my main component is able to fetch data from json file using an api defined in my django view and url file.

I do not understand how after filling in my Vue form, I may directly submit data to my django database. Tutorials online utlise django's built-in form related features; this, I am not after.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use SPA like Vue or React or Angular, it will be better to make communication between frontend and back end using API

To achieve that with django you can use

> Django Rest Framework

Best of luck

Comment: If I am to use fetch api and ajax requests (not Rest), what would I need to do? I am trying to link a vue form to my django model

Comment: You can use vue top of django but it is not a good choice, you should change vue brackets to [] for example, you can read more about it but it is not a good practice, the better way is using REST

Comment: What do you mean change vue brackets? Also, do you have anything I could read to help me? I personally can only find people using django's built-in forms which is not what I am after

Comment: Check this article please

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/using-vue-js-alongside-django-template-45cbe17b3646

Comment: I have. This is not really what I am looking for. I am looking to use the fetch api, not axios/rest. Also, I am trying to simply link a vue form to my django backend so that I can submit objects into a database I have (django default).